# I need to prove that $(a^n)(b^n) = (ab)^n,$ where $a,b\in\mathbb N$. Proof by induction on $n \in \mathbb Z, n\geq 0$.

Tags: induction, exponentiation

I need to prove that $(a^n)(b^n) = (ab)^n,$ where $a,b\in\mathbb N$.

Since $a^0=1$, is given in the question, I assumed my base step to be when $(n=0)$.
$(a^0)(b^0)= (1)(1) 
=1.$
and now I'm stuck.
I also tried
$(a^{n+1})(b^{n+1})=(ab)^{n+1}$ 
  as my induction. 
In the question, $a^{n+1}$ is given as $(a^n)(a)$
I got to
 $(a^{n+1})(b^{n+1})=(a^na)(b^nb)$ 
and I'm stuck again.
Help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $a$ and $b$ are elements of what?

Comment: Do you have the associative and commutative laws of multiplication available to use in this proof?

Comment: $(a^na)(b^nb)=(a^nb^n)(ab)$

Comment: a and b are elements of the Natural numbers (sorry couldn't figure out that symbol). And I can use associative, commutative, distributive multiplication laws.

Comment: `$\mathbb N$` produces $\mathbb N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are allowed to use other laws such as the commutative law of multiplication.

As you mentioned before
$$a^nb^n=(ab)^n$$
for $n=0$
Now assume that it holds for $n=k$, then for $n=k+1$ we have
$$a^{k+1}b^{k+1}=a^kab^kb=a^kb^kab=(ab)^kab$$
Now recall that all exponent raised to the first power is itself, therefore $ab=(ab)^1$

$$(ab)^k(ab)^1$$

Multiplication of exponents witht he same base

$$(ab)^k(ab)^1=\boxed{(ab)^{k+1}}$$

Comment: Thank you. I can see that you are using the associative law. Where are you using the commutative law?

Comment: When changing the order of multiplication of $a^kab^kb$ to $a^kb^kab$

Answer (score 0):

multiplication is commutative and associative.

$(a^{n+1})(b^{n+1}) = (a^na)(b^nb) = a^n\cdot a\cdot b^n \cdot b= a^n\cdot b^n\cdot a\cdot b=$

$(a^nb^n)(ab) = (ab)^n (ab)= (ab)^{n+1}$.